# How to update value of checkbox in db using Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Trying to do a simple todo app with flask and sqlalchemy and since I have never worked with checkboxes in flask before, i have the following problem.

App is

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(200))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)


@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    print(request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

HTML IS:

```
<ul>
    {% for todo in incomplete %}
    <li><input id="checkbx" name="{{ todo.id }}" type="checkbox"> {{ todo.text }} </li>
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

when I,

```
print(request.form)
```

after selecting the checkbox to complete the todo task and clicking the update button, console prints out:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('11', u'on')])
```

how can i update the DB to change the complete value from '0' to '1'?

```
print(request.form['checkbx'])
```

> gives a 400 Bad Request

```
request.form.get('checkbx')
```

> returns None

```
todo = request.form.getlist('checkbx')
```

> returns []

I'm guessing i need to do something like:

```
todo = Todo.query.filter_by(int(id)).first()
```

so then I can

```
todo.complete = True
db.session.commit()
```

how  can i get the id from that ImmutableMultiDict (in this case it's '11') ???

Comment: I specifically changed the id to "checkbx" from "checkbox" to see where i'm going wrong. also adding a value doesn't change a thing. request.form.getlist('checkbox')[1] continues to return []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert the ImmutableMultiDict to dict

```
todo = dict(request.form).keys[0]
```

and then filter by it, complete and commit.

Comment: data = request.form.to_dict() might be easier

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped, I also found this website after your comment. http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-get-a-dict-from-flask-request-form/